# Hide Button but keep function - XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, visual-studio-2017

First I've tried to implement a Click Event to my Textbox. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with XAML.
So, my plan is to add a Button and whenever you click this Button, the textfield below should change it's letter (back to 1).
My idea was to put the button over the first textbox and to hide it, so that you see the first textbox.

But, if I set the button as hidden, my function doesn't work anymore.
Is there a solution to hide the button, but, still keep the function for the second textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hidden means control is loaded, takes up space on the screen, but won't be operational(clickable), so it doesn't help you.

You could edit the button's ControlTemplate and make it a simple Grid with Transparent background, without the Hidden part of course.

And last thing, you could add MouseDown function on your TextBox so you won't need the button at all.

Comment: I've never done XAML before so I really don't know how to use the MouseDown Function. Can you show me?

I guess I have to add in .xaml :MouseDown ="txtOne_MouseDown" 
 and in .cs: private void txtOne_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            txtTwo.Text = "1";
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you use bindings and commands you have two ways:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ClickCommand}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

or

```
<TextBlock Text="Some text">
    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftClick" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"/>
    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

.xaml:

```
 <TextBox MinWidth="90" x:Name="txtBoden" TextChanged="TxtBoden_TextChanged" 
  PreviewMouseDown="txtBoden_MouseDown"></TextBox>
```

.cs:

```
    public void txtBoden_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        txtFach.Text = "1";
    }
```